# WriteInt not sending the integer

Tags: java, client, server

I am writing a client server program. everything is working except for this part. while looking at my code i found out that the server is not receiving the user id sent by the client. the problem is either in  `outToServer.writeInt(uid);
or in uid = din.readInt();`.

Thank you very much.

Here is the code for the **server part:**

```
if("Create Event".equals(command)){    
    String eventnametxt = datain.readLine();
    System.out.println(eventnametxt);
    String location = datain.readLine();
    System.out.println(location);
    String description = datain.readLine();
    System.out.println(description);
    String startdate = datain.readLine();
    System.out.println(startdate);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    String enddate = datain.readLine();
    System.out.print(enddate);
    uid = din.readInt();
    System.out.print(uid);
    //get the fullname of the user creating the event
    condition = "userid = "+uid;
    String Creator = jdbc.SelectLogIn("fullName", "users", condition);
    //insert the record in the database
    String Fields = "EventName,Location,Description,Creator,userid,StartDate,EndDate";
    String Values = "'" + eventnametxt + "','" + location + "','" + description + "','" + Creator + "'," + uid + ",'" + startdate + "','" + enddate + "'";
    jdbc.Insert("events", Fields, Values);
    dataout.writeBytes("Event Successfully Created!!\n");
}
```

and this is the code for the **client side:**

```
command = "Create Event";

try{
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6555);
    inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    //inform the server that user is creating an event
    outToServer.writeBytes(command + '\n');
    //send the information for the event
    outToServer.writeBytes(eventnametxt.getText() + '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(locationtxt.getText() + '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(Eventdescription.getText() + '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(startdt.getDate().toString() + '\n');
    outToServer.writeBytes(enddt.getDate().toString()+'\n');
    // send the userid corresponding to the person logged in and creating the event
    outToServer.writeInt(uid);
    System.out.print("   "+uid+'\n');

    response = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.print("server response: "+response);
    if("Event Successfully Created!!".equals(response)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response, "InfoBox: " + "Response", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        outToServer.writeBytes("Event Added"+'\n');
        this.dispose();
    }
}catch (IOException ex){
    Logger.getLogger(EventsFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your server code, you're reading your lines from 'datain' but your uid from 'socket'.

Comment: i am reading the strings using a buffered reader and the integers using DataInputStream

Comment: You should read them exactly on the same way as you write them. You have written everything (also the stings) with DataOutputStream, you should read everything (also the stings) with DataInputStream (keeping the order),

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputSteam instead of DataInputStream and DataOutputSteam. It takes care of your Serializable objects like String and Date with writeObject() and readObject(). And you do not need to convert those things to String and put \n at the end to be able to read it with readLine() later. Those classes also support the basic types like int with writeInt() and readInt().
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Server side code:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(6555);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    //This code should go to a thread for async processing
                    ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                    ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    process(oIn, oOut);
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    private static void process(ObjectInputStream datain, ObjectOutputStream dataout) {
        try {
            String command = (String) datain.readObject();
            if ("Create Event".equals(command)) {
                String eventnametxt = (String) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(eventnametxt);
                String location = (String) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(location);
                String description = (String) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(description);
                Date startdate = (Date) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(startdate);

                Date enddate = (Date) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(enddate);
                int uid = datain.readInt();
                System.out.println(uid);

                // JDBC part comes here ...

                dataout.writeObject("Event Successfully Created!!");
                dataout.flush(); // This will send 'Event Successfully Created!!' to client

                String confirmation = (String) datain.readObject();
                System.out.println(confirmation);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side code:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String eventnametxt = "Education";
        String locationtxt = "Classroom";
        String Eventdescription = "Math";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date startdt = sdf.parse("2015-04-27 08:00");
        Date enddt = sdf.parse("2015-04-27 09:00");
        int uid = 100;

        String command = "Create Event";
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6555);
            ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            // inform the server that user is creating an event
            outToServer.writeObject(command);
            // send the information for the event
            outToServer.writeObject(eventnametxt);
            outToServer.writeObject(locationtxt);
            outToServer.writeObject(Eventdescription);
            outToServer.writeObject(startdt);
            outToServer.writeObject(enddt);
            // send the userid corresponding to the person logged in and
            // creating the event
            outToServer.writeInt(uid);
            outToServer.flush(); // This will send everything to server in one step

            ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String response = (String) inFromServer.readObject();
            System.out.print("server response: " + response);
            if ("Event Successfully Created!!".equals(response)) {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null, response, "InfoBox: " + "Response", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                outToServer.writeObject("Event Added");
                outToServer.flush(); // This will send 'Event Added' to server
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server console output after running:

```
Education
Classroom
Math
Mon Apr 27 08:00:00 CEST 2015
Mon Apr 27 09:00:00 CEST 2015
100
Event Added
```

Client console output after running:

```
server response: Event Successfully Created!!
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. please help my project is due Monday and i lost two days searching what the problem might be. thank you

Comment: its not working. for some reason the client is only printing client now running and then it does not perform anything and the server would print accepted connection but nothing happens. its like the program is stuck in a loop and i can't find it.

Comment: I just copy-pasted this code back to eclipse. I started the server and then the client. And it produces the same output I described. I use java7. But this code should compile and work with 6 and 5 as well.

Comment: Thanks again. i rewrote every line and check it before adding the other one. everything was sent just fine to the server except for the integer even with the ObjectInputStream it didn't send it and that's why is just freezing and not doing anything. I will see what to do with it